# Golang websocket client

Tags: go, websocket

I want to make client websocket connections to exertnal server each connection = goroutine and reader. I was looking informations on the internet but I found how to create server websocket tutorials.
Can anyone be so kind and make a trivial example and walk me through. I am using standart golang libary https://golang.org/x/net/websocket.

I created some code but when I closed one connection program exited with EOF information. I won't post the code because it's probably bad duo to the fact it was my first try.

I know how to read/send message from websocket but I don't know how to create multiple connections.

Any informations, examples would be appreciate, thanks for reading

Comment: First link has sever in golang but client is in JS, second library to websocket I think I am too dumb beacuse I dont see there any reference to create goroutine(new connection) which my question is about. I just want to know how should look correct code to create new separated connection to websocket in goroutine.

Comment: Before spending time on the x/net/websocket package, [read this](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages).

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Gorilla WebSocket library](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket)

Here's an [example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go) of it's use as a client

Answer (score 6):

Golang [official doc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) recommends to use [gorilla](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) for building websocket based application. Still the problem is, **gorilla websocket is not event based**. Applications need to handle concurrent read and write operations. Developers need to **write custom goroutines** for handling connect, disconnect and read events. 
I think it is better to have a library handling everything for you.
So, I decided to write down my own [client implementation - gowebsocket](https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-go) on top of gorilla. You can find more detailed explaination here [Getting started with websocket client in go](https://medium.com/@sachinshinde7676/getting-started-with-websocket-client-in-go-73baaf8b5caf)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the comparison given on this link.

https://yalantis.com/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/4265/websocket-libraries.png

Article suggests to go for Gobwas(https://github.com/gobwas/ws). Its best performance wise and offers all the required features needed for websockets related applications.